# Material design in R Shiny Application, collapse and expand card

Tags: r, shiny, materialize, shinyjs

I have some experience building R-Shiny apps but I'm new to material design.  Stumbled across the shinymaterial package and it's great, however, missing some functionality that the shiny-bootstrap UI frameworks  provide such as accordion/expansion panel.

There is material_card() in shinymaterial package to create card, I'm wondering if there is a way to add a bit of HTML to enable expand/collapse functionality for the material_card function,  using tags$div for HTML and/or tags$script for js.

Here is my (sad) attempt below. See reprex:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinymaterial)

# Wrap shinymaterial apps in material_page
ui <- material_page(
  title = "Basic Page + Side-Nav + Tabs",
  # Place side-nav in the beginning of the UI
  material_side_nav(
    fixed = FALSE,
    tags$h3("Side-Nav Content")
  ),
  # Define tabs
  material_row(
    material_tabs(
      tabs = c(
        "First Tab" = "first_tab",
        "Second Tab" = "second_tab"
      )
    ),
    material_column(width = 8,
  # Define tab content
               material_tab_content(
    tab_id = "first_tab",
    material_card(title = "mycard",
    tags$h1("First Tab Content"),
    tags$div(
      HTML("<mat-card>
             <mat-card-header>
             <mat-card-title style='font-size: 20px;'>mycard</mat-card-title>
             </mat-card-header>
             <mat-card-content *ngIf='!collapsed'>
             <p>This is some example text.</p>
             <p>This text will disappear when you use the action button in the actions bar below.</p>
             </mat-card-content>
             <mat-card-actions>
             <button mat-button (click)='collapsed=true'>Collapse text</button>
             <button mat-button (click)='collapsed=false'>Uncollapse text</button>
             </mat-card-actions>
             </mat-card>")
    )
    )
                 
  ),
  material_tab_content(
    tab_id = "second_tab",
    material_card(title = NULL,
    tags$h1("Second Tab Content")
    )
 )
 ),
 material_column(width=4,
                 div(style='padding:15px;'),
                 material_tabs(
                   tabs = c(
                     "Third Tab" = "third_tab",
                     "Fourth Tab" = "fourth_tab"
                   )
                 ),
    material_tab_content(
      tab_id = "third_tab",
      material_card(title = NULL,
      tags$h1("Third Tab Content")
      )
  ),
    material_tab_content(
      tab_id = "fourth_tab",
      material_card(title = NULL,
      tags$h1("Fourth Tab Content")
      )
    )
)
)
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: not an answer to your question - anyway might be useful: there is a package called `shinybs` which you can use to [collapse different elements](https://ebailey78.github.io/shinyBS/docs/Collapses.html)

Comment: Thanks @ClaudH, I wasn't able to get things working using div in the above example, and accordions in ```shinydashboardPlus``` package seemed to negatively interact with ```shinymaterial::material_page()``` (weird black box occasionally appears in window), using ```bs4Dash::bs4Accordion()``` seems to work fine with ```shinymaterial::material_page()```, just remember to add  ```shinyWidgets::useBs4Dash()``` in UI to use the functions from ```bs4Dash```